# Use master-theorem to solve 4T(n/2) + n^2(logn)^3

Tags: recursion, recurrence, master-theorem

I'm studying for a midterm and came across this problem that I never understood. How can one apply the master theorem to 4T(n/2) + n^2(logn)^3? It is not obvious to me how it applies to any of the three cases. n^2(logn)^3 differs from n^2 by a function, not by a constant, so what case does it fall under?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because probably belongs on maths site

Comment: There are many other questions about master theorem on this website that are not closed.

Comment: Case 2. Look carefully at the condition for it.